# Zuul PredecorationFilter X-Forwarded-Prefix header leads to duplicate path in Spring ForwardedHeaderFilter

Tags: spring-mvc, netflix-zuul, spring-hateoas

SpringBoot 2.3.0, SpringMVC, latest spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul.

I have a ZUUL proxy service which has the following rule:

```
zuul.routes.service1.path=/campaigns/**
zuul.routes.service1.url=http://localhost:8081/campaignmanagement/campaigns
```

The forwarded request contains correct `X-Forwarded-*` headers AND the incorrect `X-Forwarded-Prefix`: "campaigns"

If I request http://proxy:8080/campaigns, the target service (`service1`), generates this url: **http://proxy:8080/campaigns/campaigns** when i call

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toUriString()
```

**(Notice the duplicate "campaigns" path!)**

I use the SpringBoot config property `server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`.

The `ForwardedHeaderFilter` appends to the current SpringMVC path to the forwardedPrefix:

```
    private String initRequestUri() {
      return this.forwardedPrefix != null ? this.forwardedPrefix + this.pathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest)this.delegate.get()) : null;
    }
```

Can I do anything here? is ZUUL the problem or the ForwardedHeaderFilter.

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same problem. I don't know if the only solution is to create a custom Zuul filter to remove this header at the beginning with the highest predence.

I know that it is possible to enable/disable per header with Spring Cloud Gateway but I think is not possible with Zuul.

Comment: Removing the header is not good because it is needed to construct the correct path. The problem is the following line in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.PreDeorationFilter.addProxyPrefix() "newPrefixBuilder.append(route.getPrefix())". This appends a "route prefix" to context path although this is NO prefix. I have to find out, how the "prefix" is set on a org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.Route.